# Sonarqube PASS even though theresholds are too low

Tags: java, gradle, sonarqube

I have a out of the box Sonarqube instance (using docker).

The problem I am having is that several of the quality checks are failing (I have a blocking issue, coverage is below 80%) but the Quality Gate shows GREEN and PASS.

I am running the build from gradle using the Sonarqube plugin.  SonarQube is v 6.4

What am I missaing?

Answer (score 0):

by default, the 80% on quality gate only applies to the new code that has been shipped from the data took as a reference.

If i remember well, by default that diff is "computed" between project versions (at least if gradle sonar runner is used).

so, if your new code has more than 80% of coverage, quality gate will be ok; even if the whole project does not reach that 80%.

The idea of this default configuration is to avoid having always a failed quality gate on legacy projects where there is already tech debt.

**Edit:** It seems the reason for "blocker" not failing a quality gate is a matter of terminology confusion. OP has a blocker, but it's not a bug/vulnerability but instead a "code smell". [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#content/view/6966822) you have a brief explanation of the sonarqube categories and severities.

**Edit2:** Also, [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#content/view/9012048) you have an explanation of which are default quality gate metrics

Comment: I was just using coverage as an example - I have a blocking issue, which the gate is supposed to have 0 tolerance for.

Comment: being coverage or issue does not change anything regarding the explanation. From my understanding, the key here is if that blocking issue was reported as "new code" (quality gate, by default, applies to that) or instead as a tech debt your project already had. When looking into sonarqube project overview page, do you see blocking issue on the "right column", or only the left one? Right column is about the new code (a screenshot will be easier to explain).

Comment: Here a couple of screen shots https://www.dropbox.com/s/a3jyafblloeh5mu/gporev-data-svc.pdf?dl=0

Comment: you have a blocker "code smell" , not bug/vulnerability. Regarding "right column" i was talking about, you don't have it (yet). i guess since you are still on first version and there is no code reference to build incremental against.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by creating my own Quality Gate and NOT tying it to leak period.